How to refer to a single subnet id created from a module of multiple subnets in terraform
I am trying to pull out a specific subnet id from a module in terraform that created VNETs/Subnets from a map object varaible previously.  I seem to be failing obtaining the subnet_id for the depends_on property in the data block, else it will look for the resource before it gets created.
main.tf
data "azurerm_subnet" "pri-subnet" {
  name                 = var.pri_subnet
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm-vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm-vnet.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [module.network.subnet_id[var.pri_subnet]]
}

resource "azurerm_redis_cache" "redis-cache" {
...
}

Error:
Initializing Terraform Cloud...
Initializing modules...
╷
│ Error: Invalid expression
│
│   on redis_cache.tf line 6, in data "azurerm_subnet" "pri-subnet":
│    6:   depends_on = [module.network.subnet_id[var.pri_subnet]]
│
│ A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template expressions, etc are       
│ allowed here.

VNET/SUBNET module main.tf
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  for_each            = var.vnets
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.vnet_rg_name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = [each.value.address_space]
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each             = local.subnets
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet[each.value.vnet_name].name
  resource_group_name  = var.vnet_rg_name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.subnet_address]
}

output "vnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.*.id 
}

output "subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.subnet.*.id 
}

vnet/subnet varaibles.tf
variable "vnets" {
  type = map(object({
    address_space = string
    subnets = list(object({
      subnet_name    = string
      subnet_address = string
    }))
  }))

  default = {
    "AGV-L-VNET-001" = {
      address_space = "10.1.0.0/16",
      subnets = [
        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-AP-10.1.1.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.1.1.0/24"
        },

        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-ED-10.1.2.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.1.2.0/24"
        },

        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-DB-10.1.3.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.1.3.0/24"
        },
        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-PA-10.1.4.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.1.4.0/24"
        }
        ,
        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-AGW-10.1.5.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.1.5.0/24"
        },
        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-PRI-10.1.6.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.1.6.0/24"
        },
      ]
    },
    "AGV-L-VNET-002" = {
      address_space = "10.2.0.0/16",
      subnets = [
        {
          subnet_name    = "AGV-L-SNT-AKS-10.2.0.0_24"
          subnet_address = "10.2.0.0/24"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

vnet module deploy - vnet.tf
module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"

  vnets        = var.vnets
  location     = local.location
  vnet_rg_name = var.net_rg_name
  tags         = local.net-tags

}


Just leave it as depends_on = [module.network]

... but if you are creating the resource you should not be using data "azurerm_subnet" you should get what you need from the module
